# Is it safe to use variable session data?

Tags: php, session

I have a (hopefully) quick question regarding sessions. Whilst I have used sessions extensively, I have not used them in a situation whereby the values change depending on a users actions.

After logging in to my application, a user can select a company area, which has many levels of pages and folders. All of these pages will need this 'company_id'. At the moment I send the company_id via GET, but as I get deeper into the application this is becoming increasingly hard to maintain, with various other data being stored in the URL.

Therefore, when a user selects their company, I could set their company_id in $_SESSION array. However, when a user changes company, I would then need to change $_SESSION['company_id'] to the new value.

Is this a good use of sessions? I could potentially clean up my urls by using session data rather than always using GET, but I am unsure if this is a recommended way of using sessions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perfectly good use of session data

Comment: Hiding URL data in sessions is imo a crap practice. What if at some point somebody needs access to multiple companies. What if somebody wants to share a link?

Comment: @PeeHaa I see your point. However, there is no possible way the application will allow a user to view multiple companies at once, and these are pages of an application not a public site, and urls will not ever be shared

Comment: @PeeHaa However, is there another way? Sessions, GET or POST seem like the only options and POST has the same limitations you mention, plus you have to use forms on every page!

Comment: "and urls will not ever be shared" Ok so you are going to personally check on this at every client?

Comment: It's a web application, one that users have permission to view only certain areas and need to log in - whilst anybody could copy and paste the URL, it wouldn't work and it wouldn't be expected to work, like sharing a link to your account on online banking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad implementation of the HTTP design philosophy. All HTTP requests should be **self contained**, *RESTful*. All information needed to get a specific page should be present in the request itself (URL, headers and body), **not dependent on hidden state.**

Super trivial example: you can't copy a URL to someplace or someone else and have them see the same page. The content of the page is dependent on session state, which has been laboriously set through the visit history of several previous pages. To return to this same page, you need to retrace the same steps, recreating some hidden server-side state to arrive at the same page.

This gets even more complex and messier if you take into account that a visitor may want to open pages requiring different states in two or more simultaneous tabs/windows.

All this isn't to say that it *can't* work, only that it's hideously complex and will break the usual expected behaviour of browsers, unless you really bend over backwards to somehow prevent that.

Comment: Accepted answer as issue of 2 tabs/windows is the stand out reason not to implement. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @deceze, I appreciate a fair amount of time has passed here! However, what are your thoughts on using HTML sessions storage to solve the issue in the OP? Thanks

Comment: You mean HTML5 Local Storage or such? Same thing. It doesn't really matter *where* you store state, the mere fact that there's state external to the URL will screw with default browser behavior and expectations. Use a Javascript driven app and live with the fact that you cannot deep link to specific content, if this is really necessary...

Comment: I see, but for a complex web application (rather than a website as such) where you and only you can access 'your data', and the data I need to store in this instance will change anyway whilst browsing (what I'm saying is I would never expect to get to a certain page directly with through a url) is this still bad implementation?

Comment: Well, again, browser history, back/forward and multiple tabs will be screwed up. You decide. — One solution actually would be to save all the state variables somewhere (e.g. session) with a unique id (each possible state having one unique id) and use that id in the URL. Essentially, externalize the variable storage from the URL to the session. You'll still have a unique URL for each page, but short URLs. Uses a lot of server side storage though.

Comment: In what way will the browser history and back/ forward be messed up? And in terms of tabs my understanding was that HTML5 session storage was tab independent, meaning opening a different tab would mean no leaking of data? Please don't think I'm disagreeing, I just want to fully understand

Answer (score 1):

If the *many levels of pages and levels* are per-company, you can put the *company_id* in a specific include file - this part of the site being dedicated to a given company.

However if they're shared by multiple companies, and this is probably what you want, this is potentially misleading, or even dangerous depending on the user actions, since the user may jump to a given page (link...) and access a page with unexpected data linked to a company which ID is provided by the session or cookie.

You could dynamically build the links on a page, based on IDs, to ensure consistency during the navigation from **that** page. Any direct "jump" to another part of the site will not carry the ID with it (and the page may offer to select a company).

Depending on your web server and if you have control over it you could build the URL having "company ID" as an element of the URL path, not the GET parameters

Eg

```
http://example.com/invoicing/company382/listprices.php
```

using a rewrite (web server configuration) to change the URL to be actually used to

```
http://example.com/invoicing/listprices.php?compid=company382
```

(URL not visible to the user) that informs of the company ID via the GET parameters.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful - especially for the rewrite idea, would make the URL's much prettier.